# problem with adding php code with variables using printf in linux

Tags: python, bash

The problem is ,  when i'am using python to execute that command line

```
  os.system("sudo -u "+self.user+" printf "+ self.data +"  > "+ self.path)
```

is updating the file with new data but not with variables just with space 
example

```
<?php
$test = "dddd";
echo "please work".$test;
```

will be after execute command line to

```
<?php
 = "dddd";
 echo "please work".;
```

without variables 
So how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: You should surround with a single quote:  `os.system("..." + "printf '" + self.data + "' > .."` (Note the single quote). Also, you wouldn't have run into this issue had you used Popen with a list argument instead of os.system(..).

Comment: it's solved the problem but the code added in  the file with " code " like a string